# Prefix Increment before same name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

how to auto increment the prefix from (00 to 99)if same name comes?

```
ex:- Kiran,Kiran,Kiran
Then
ANS:= 01 Kiran 
      02 Kiran
      etc
```

note =no space

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using one of the [split string functions](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) from here:

```
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str='Kiran,Kiran,Kiran'

;with cte
as
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by item order by item)as rn
 from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@str,',') 
 )
 select item,
 case when rn<10 then '0' +cast(rn as varchar(2)) else cast(rn  as varchar(2) ) end from cte
```

Output:

```
item    (No column name)
Kiran   01
Kiran   02
Kiran   03
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, my Parser function already returns the sequence.  For example:

```
Declare @String varchar(max)='Kiran,Kiran,Kiran'
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,',')
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       Kiran
2       Kiran
3       Kiran
```

> Now, with a little twist, you can format your desired results

```
Select Seq= RIGHT('00'+cast(Key_PS as varchar(10)),2),ParseVal=Key_Value from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,',')
```

Returns

```
Seq ParseVal
01  Kiran
02  Kiran
03  Kiran
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Kiran,Kiran,Kiran',',')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL , Key_Value varchar(max))

As

Begin
   Declare @intPos int,@SubStr varchar(max)
   Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@Delimeter, @String)
   Set @String = Replace(@String,@Delimeter+@Delimeter,@Delimeter)
   While @IntPos > 0
      Begin
         Set @SubStr = Substring(@String, 0, @IntPos)
         Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@SubStr)
         Set @String = Stuff(@String, 1, Len(@SubStr+@Delimeter), '');  
         Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@Delimeter, @String)
      End
   Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@String)
   Return 
End
```